# Docker NodeMCU ESP32 recipe for target 'build' failed

Tags: docker, nodemcu

On OSX 10.13.6 I get the following failure in an ESP32 build using marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h', needed by '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/build/luac_cross/uzlib_deflate.d'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/build/luac_cross'
/opt/nodemcu-firmware/components/luac_cross/component.mk:5: recipe for target 'build' failed
make[2]: *** [build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/build/luac_cross'
/opt/nodemcu-firmware/sdk/esp32-esp-idf/make/project.mk:552: recipe for target 'component-luac_cross-build' failed
make[1]: *** [component-luac_cross-build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware'
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Docker image? If in doubt just do a `docker pull marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build`.

Comment: yes, I've updated both the docker image and dev-esp32 git branch.  I used to be able to build an image without Bluetooth support but now it fails with or without Bluetooth with the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you were looking for but...

This appears to be a known issue. At https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2779 a few people are discussing an issue that looks a lot like yours.